# StopIteration when mocking base class of own class

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, magicmock, stopiteration

In a rather complex test scenario I need to mock the base class of one of my own classes and  instantiate the latter several times. When I do that my test errors with a `StopIteration` exception. Here's what my scenario boils down to in this respect:

Code under test (`my_class.py`):

```py
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

class MySession(OAuth2Session):
    pass

class MyClass:
    def init(self, x):
        self.x = x
        client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=x)
        self.session = MySession(client=client)
```

Test code (`test_mock.py`):

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session') as MockSession:
    from my_class import MyClass

cls = MyClass()

class MockTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mock_1(self):
        cls.init(1)
        self.assertIsNotNone(cls.session)

    def test_mock_2(self):
        cls.init(2)
        self.assertIsNotNone(cls.session)
```

Test result:

```
$ python -m unittest test_mock
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_mock_2 (test_mock.MockTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\test_mock.py", line 16, in test_mock_2
    cls.init(2)
  File "...\my_class.py", line 11, in init
    self.session = MySession(client=client)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1093, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1097, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1154, in _execute_mock_call
    result = next(effect)
StopIteration

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I have debugged into the `unittest.mock.MagicMock` class but I can't figure out what's going on. In MagicMock's `_execute_mock_call()` method I noticed that `self.side_effect` is a tuple iterator object and when `next()` is called on that in the second test (`test_mock_2`) it results in the `StopIteration`.

Both tests run "OK" if I don't use the `MySession` subclass, i.e. `self.session = OAuth2Session(client=client)` in MyClass' `init()` method. (But that's just not how the real code under test works...)

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock class which you directly use, because your custom class inherit Mock and next starts unexpected behavior.

Rewrite path method to your custom class.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('my_class.MySession') as MockSession:
    from my_class import MyClass
```

Comment: Okay, maybe I oversimplified my test scenario: In fact, the `init()` method of `MyClass` has two branches with one using `MySession` and the other using the base `OAuth2Session` class. So I need to mock both and I had hoped I could get along mocking the base class. But your answer already pointed me in the right direction: Nesting two `with patch()` statements around the `my_class` import works.